# Is there a way to "Turn off" solution folders?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

We have a large solution with 86 projects. Everything is divided up into "solution folders". I find it rather difficult to find what I'm looking for. Is there a way to turn off solution folders just for me without affecting anyone else using the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered navigating to a file by keyboard?

Visual Assist has an "Open file in solution" dialog which very convenient due to instant search. If you don't have VAssist (which you really should) I believe the free DPack has some equivalent.

If you need to perform file-specific operations in the solution tree, you can bind this macro to a key and execute it after opening a file:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.TrackActivityinSolutionExplorer")
DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.TrackActivityinSolutionExplorer")
DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()
```

This will track your file in the solution tree and focus on it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, not directly.

You could probably [write a macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) that clears them out of the solution file, just for you, however.